# Transfer data in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases on separate servers (dev and production) I need to move my data from dev to production from multiple tables without affecting the pre-existing data on production. Any idea if SQL Manager support something like this or am I going to have to write a script for it?

My situation in detail:

I have a tool which allow me to create surveys for my company. The tool is located on dev and also on production. Since I don't want to add test data in my production db I am using the dev version of the tool to create my surveys and test them locally. The tool is tied to few tables in my db such as surveys, questions, anwers, results, etc.

My current setup: When I am done with a survey and it is ready to launch, I have to use the production version of the tool to manually redo all of the previous work that i did on production. This is not ideal at all not only because of the time that I have to spend doing it but also risking making mistakes during the manual copying.

What I need to do:
Those tables that I mentioned above, already have production data in them and they are available for my company to use. When I create a new survey I need to transfer only the specific records of the new survey (from all tables) from dev to production without affecting anything that I had there from before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Import and Export Data`](http://algconsultings.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/import-data-into-sql-server/)

Or Add the DEV server as a linked server in your PROD server and then use INSERT/SELECT statements

Comment: can you give me more info on how to add the server as a linked server? never done it before.

Comment: Login to your production DB server, expand Server Objects, then right click on Linked servers and choose New Linked Server. Fill in the IP or hostname of the DEV server into the Linked server field, from server type choose SQL Server. Choose Security tab from the left, choose the last option "Be made using this security context", fill in the username and password of the DEV server then click OK.

Comment: You can then query like this:
INSERT INTO dbo.table(id,name)
SELECT id,name FROM [SERVER-IP/Hostname].[DBName].[dbo].[DevTable]

Comment: that sounds like something that could actually work for my situation. thanks! I will mark this as accepted as soon as I test it and make sure it works.

Comment: I followed everything you posted but is giving me an error. "The linked server was created but failed a connection test" I put the correct info in Security tab and all. Anything else that I should look up?

Comment: if the test failed, that means there is something wrong with information you entered

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18319/discussion-between-bader-and-crematorio)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a database compare tool, for SQL Server I use SQL Delta, wich allows you to automatically create a script to run in the database you wish, http://www.sqldelta.com/

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find any out-of-the-box solutions for this, but there are tools that can help once you've got a clear idea of what you're trying to accomplish -- *in detail*.  A little time spent at this point to make sure you're really clear on what you expect to have happen will pay huge dividends when you move to production.

The scenario you're describing sounds like you've got some configuration-type data in your database alongside your transactional, or domain data.  In other words, you've got changes that need to be promoted from your development environment to production in order for your application to work properly.  This isn't unusual, but you've got to be pretty deliberate and very careful when you set up a promotion plan for a scenario like this -- after all, you don't want to push test data to your production system along with your configuration changes.  It's critical, therefore, to identify the tables you're going to push from dev to prod and make sure those are the only tables you're pushing in that direction.

You also mentioned something about "without affecting the pre-existing data on production".  Can you tell us more about this (maybe an example)?  Typically, you'd want to keep specific tables (by convention) set up to move changes in one direction only -- ie, from dev to prod.  If you've got tables that need to contain merged changes, you're going to have to apply even more attention to getting this right, because you need to deal with merge errors -- what happens when you've got data to push and it's already present in the target database, for instance?

Once you've got a plan for what you actually want to move, some of the tools mentioned in other answers would probably work, or check out Redgate's tools (like [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)) -- they make some really nice products to help with DB management tasks.

---- addendum ----

Based on edits to the question, here are a couple of additional thoughts:

(1) Allow your production surveys to have a "disabled" or "testing" mode, so you don't have to make your data changes in another environment.  This allows you to be able to move stuff from dev to production only when actual development changes exist.

(2) Define a "package" mechanism to move a survey from one environment to another.  This would allow you to deal with merge conflicts, ID changes, etc., generically and reliably.  As a bonus, this would allow you to also move a production survey back to dev for debugging and testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I will edit my post to include an example of what I am trying to accomplish.